# WooCommerce back-end very slow takes 10 seconds to load, slow queries

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My WooCommerce back-end is very slow. We are on a dedicated VPS so that should not be the problem (we already moved to another hosting because we thought that it was an hosting issue).

I did also configure redis caching so that also is not the problem.

Sometimes the product / order page takes so long to load the page goes blank. We also tried to disable every plugin and see if any plugin was a issue but that was also not the case.

Here is the query monitor output of the slow query:

[image: query monitor]

The website I am talking about is: https://www.ruitershopboxmeer.nl/

Does someone know why the loading time is so slow? Because this is not workable.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is this still a problem? And what is your principal use of the admin panel normally?